# Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, sonarqube, azure-devops

We want to analyze source code with SonarQube from TFS-on premises.
Followed exact configuration From - https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS

The project is getting build with zero error but stuck with this below error -

[image: Error Image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this VSBuild task? could you please share your build definition and the configuration?

Comment: Enable MSBuild detailed or diagnostics logging to check why.

Comment: @Jayendran yes..VSBuild Task..

Comment: @Jayendran yes..VSBuild Task.. Selected Version "Latest" and "MSBuild Arguments" -  /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" , Platform - any cpu , Configuration - release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successfully build the project and with Zero error task was getting failed. After a day research, finally found that my web application is having some functions with Microsoft office and feature Package was not installed with the Microsoft Office.
And after building at the time of publishing it was throwing the error.